# What's wrong with setup and integration of python and created database using Sqlite?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I use python 3.5.2 and SQLite 3 in order to create a database and table using shell. I used following code:

> import sqlite3
> conn=sqlite3.connect('TestDB.db');
>
> c = conn.cursor()
>
> c.execute('''CREATE TABLE CLIENTS ([generated_id]INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, [Client_Name]text)''';

And it seems to work because I face with no error and the program creates Database file exactly with the characteristics above. The file exists in "C:\Python" directory but when I want to manipulate the file through the SQLite on CMD with the following commands:

> .open C:\Python\TestDB.db
>
> .database

It gives me an output of:

> main: C:WINDOWS\system32\PythonTestDb.db

However normally just like others, it should have been like this:

> main: C:\Python\TestDB.db

However the file doesn't even exist in following System32 directory! Because of this miss_configuration I can't manipulate the data on table and it gives me an error of:

> "No such table: CLIENTS"

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a Python problem, but with the execution of SQLite's `.open` command.

Comment: I do open other Database files which is already created using "sqlite3 D:\newDb.db" command without any problem.

Comment: Yes, because in that case, you are relying on the OS (and shell) to pass the first argument as file-to-be-opened to Sqlite. If you start sqlite by itself, the OS and shell are less relevant.

Comment: If you open other database files with a command line argument, why not open your `testDB.db` file that way as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [SQLite documentation on its command line shell](https://sqlite.org/cli.html), section 2:

> You might want to use a full pathname to ensure that the file is in the directory that you think it is in. Use forward-slashes as the directory separator character. In other words use "c:/work/ex1.db", not "c:\work\ex1.db".

Thus, try

```
.open C:/Python/TestDB.db
```

(Note: the fact that `Python` and `TestDB.db` got concatenated in the filename was a giveaway. The `C:WINDOWS\system32\` directory is probably the default working directory, where `sqlite.exe` is executed, or perhaps located.
In most programming and related things, the backslash is reserved for escaping (special) characters. Neither `P` nor `T` are special, so they were replaced with their actual value, resulting in `PythonTestDB.db`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just changed it to forward slashes and it worked! So forward-slashes are directory separator in SQLite 3?

Comment: Yes. As they are in Linux/Unix/MacOS/plenty of other OSes (and consequently programming languages. Python even accepts both `\\` (escaped backslashes) and `/' in its `os` module for directory separators). Windows/DOS is the odd (inconvenient) one out.